# Get results in nested objects

Tags: mongodb

This is my collection structure and I want to filter all the results for a defined reference:

```
{
    "_id" : "5xFusfnvRobfMhRKE",
    "book" : "Lorem",
    "publisher" : "Lorem",
    "author" : "Lorem",
    "edition" : [
        {
            "edition" : "Lorem",
            "year" : 2015,
            "section" : [
                {
                    "pageNumbers" : "12",
                    "reference" : "4NoHjACkjHJ8mavv9"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My attempt was `Collection.find({'edition.section.reference': '4NoHjACkjHJ8mavv9'})`, but that doesn't work. I would expect this matches the above example.

Comment: Your query should work. Are you sure that the record you show in your post exists in your collection?

Comment: What's not working about the query you're trying?

Answer (score 0):

I think this query can help you-

```
db.collection.find({"edition.section.reference":"4NoHjACkjHJ8mavv9"},{}).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'db' before the collection_name ie. db.collection.find() and for your problem you actually did it right but just missed out on 'db'.

```
 db.sys_test.insert({"-_id":10,"edition":[{"section":[{"reference":"101"}]}]})

 db.sys_test.find({"edition.section.reference":"101"}).pretty()

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55faba519d0ff7079e6f9817"),
    "-_id" : 10,
    "edition" : [
            {
                    "section" : [
                            {
                                    "reference" : "101"
                            }
                    ]
            }
    ]
}
```